# Propagate declarative spring transaction (Grails service) to pure JDBC code

Tags: grails, jdbc, transactions, spring-transactions

I have a Grails service method which calls out to a plain Java class to save some data to a DB using JDBC.  Next, the grails service method also writes to the same DB.  This should all happen in the same transaction.

```
def dataSource

def myServiceMethod() {
    MyJDBCClass jdbcClass = new MyJDBCClass(dataSource.getConnection())
    jdbcClass.savePerson(new PersonDto("Bob"))

    Person p = Person.findByFirstName("Bob")
    p.firstName = "John"
    if (p.firstName == "John") {
        throw new RuntimeException("Test rollback of Bob")
    }
    p.save()
}
```

myServiceMethod is currently using the default propagation type: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED (since it's a service method).

MyJDBCClass is pure Java/JDBC and is in a separate JAR file which ideally we don't want any dependency on spring's transaction management.  I'm not really sure how to proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you get the connection used in MyJDBCClass?

Comment: Updated the Q in response to your comment. I believe I might have answered my own question. As long as I pass the connection and jdbcClass.savePerson doesn't commit, rollback, or alter the connection in any way I believe it works fine.  I just want to make sure this is the proper approach.

Comment: Yes, `dataSource.getConnection()` will be the same connection of your service method that's used by GORM methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, using `dataSource.getConnection()` you have the same connection used by the dynamic GORM methods.

Also it's good to note that this is the correct way of declaring a `groovy.sql.Sql` instance:

```
sql = new Sql(dataSource.getConnection())
```

If you declare like

```
sql = new Sql(dataSource)
```

it's possible that your sql commands use different connections (happens with me in Oracle databases).

Another possibility is to use the [cacheConnection](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#cacheConnection%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) closure, to ensure that all executions of groovy sql will use the same connection.